# How to make convolution with maxout activation?

Tags: python, keras

I want my activation function select maximal value, generated by `N` filters of `M x M` convolution. This layer would convert `X` channel image to 1-channel one.

How to do that?

First I wrote

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(3, (5, 5), activation='linear')
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1, strides=1))
```

but then thought it doesn't return 1-channel image, but returns 3 channel.

How to do the job?

Comment: You could trick keras and make it think your channel dimension is your rows dimension by setting the `data_format` attribute in `MaxPooling2D`, so that the max is performed on the channels instead of the rows. Didn't test it but i think this should work (supposing your data format is `(batch_size, channels, rows, cols)`):  `classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,1), strides=1, data_format='channels_last'))`

Answer (score 2):

So to apply this you shoud create a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer and [`max`](https://keras.io/backend/#max) from Backend:

```
from keras import backend as K

if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    channels_axis = 1
else:
    channels_axis = 3

# To apply MaxOut:

classifier.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.max(x, axis=channels_axis, keepdims=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`keras.backend.max`](https://keras.io/backend/#max) and give it the `axis` argument in order to take the maximum along the correct axis. Which one depends on your backend.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer, but, if you just want the result to be 1 channel, you can create a convolutional layer with only one filter. You can add it after your existing convolution, or simply change your existing convolution.

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(1, (5,5),....))
```

Comment: I want many filters, but so that only maximally reacted taken.

Comment: If you're using preset filters with custom operations, ok, but if not, maybe the model could simply learn what to do by itself.